# Is there a way to use html-files (layouts) in ioslides (R Markdown)?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I am just beginning to use ioslides to create very simple html-based presentations. In my presentation, I will often use a two-column layout (plots on the left and text on the right). I would like the columns to be of different width (60%/40%). A solution I found is to use raw html in the Markdown file itself as follows:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 60%;">
+ left hand side
</div>

<div style="float: right; width: 40%;">
+ right hand side
</div>
```

However, I would prefer to create a slide template (e.g., #twocolum-slide) in order to not always have to write html directly to the Markdown file. Is there a good solution to this? How do you handle this? I know that in using xaringan, I could simply use ".left-column" and define the columns in a css file. However, since I'd like to use html-widgets in my presentations and send them to others by email, xaringan is not a good solution.